# Which workflow technology is recommended in a loan request scenario?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, biztalk

We're going to develop an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application which needs to be workflow based.
The scenario is something like this:

*The Scenario*

> Users make request to get loan of a bank by submitting a form,
>   operators find the requests in a grid in their dashboard, they see the
>   details and if it is okay they send it to boss, and send it back to
>   users to fix or complete the request, if not. The boss decides to pay
>   loan or not, if yes and the price is below something it goes to fund
>   section, if it is above something the request goes to another boss and
>   so on..

*Requirements*

- In each state there might be some additional relevant data attached, for example the points of user calculated on time of sending the request.
- A process manager (admin) exists who can cancel any request wherever it is or pass the request to anyone he wishes.
- There might be multiple transitions available which state can move along them, the state should check the conditions and choose one transition.

*Meanwhile operators can*

- Pass requests between each other (if they're allowed to), for example if they are too busy or they're going on vacation (substituent)
- See history of requests and see what data changed in round-trips (versioning)
- Write notes before sending the request to next one or return it to someone.

*The Question*

In above scenario, which technology is more suitable and why?

- Workflow Foundation
- BizTalk

or libraries like:

- [Simple State Machine](http://simplestatemachine.codeplex.com/)
- [Jazz](http://jazz.codeplex.com/)
- [stateless](https://code.google.com/p/stateless/)
- [State Machine Compiler](http://smc.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: create a small prototype of each, see which works best for you :/

Comment: we don't have enough time to prototype each, specially all of the needed features

Answer (score 2):

I would not use BizTalk for this, even though I was a BizTalk developer for a number of years, and implemented similar workflows using it.

The reason is that I have come to the conclusion that modelling complex business workflows in BizTalk is an anathema to what BizTalk really does well, which is high performance message routing and transformations, and host integration capabilities.

However, neither would I use WF for this. I think that MS have made WF needlessly difficult to work with. I worked with WF3 which was the first version, so perhaps things have improved. But as far as I know MS removed state machine workflows from WF4 onward and now only supports sequential workflows.

So in answer to your question, I think neither are suitable for this purpose.

Why not start with NO technology stack except for ASP.NET MVC, JQuery, and SQL Server. This seems to be the MS web development standard at the moment. Likely you're already licensed for this.

Even though you seem to have your requirements up front, you'll likely find that some or even most of the requirements you have listed are subject to change or even removal.

So start with one or two core user stories which can be delivered quickly in small iterations and then continue to add features like that. When you get the point where you need to start looking at other technologies or frameworks then that is the time to reassess the decision. At this point I would personally look at using NServiceBus sagas as another option to manage your long running processes.

I think making a decision about tech stack too early in the planning process can work against you in many ways.

Sorry does not address your original question directly.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful post, state machine is added to .net 4.5 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264171.aspx